# Canot invok "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null at pageObject.LandingPage.searchItem

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

below landingpage.java code and LandingPageStepDefination.java
where to make changes so that NullPointerException issue will resolve
.................Landingpage.java.............

```
public class **LandingPage** {
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    By search=By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for Vegetables and Fruits']");
    
    By ProductName=By.cssSelector("h4.product-name");
    By topDeals=By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Top Deals']");
    public  LandingPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    public void searchItem(String name)
    {
        
        driver.findElement(search).sendKeys(name);
    }
    
    public String getProductName()
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(ProductName).getText();
    }
    public void SelectTopDealsPage()
    {
        
          driver.findElement(topDeals).click();
    }

}
```

...................landingpagestepDefination.java

```
public class LandingPageStepDefination {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public String landingproductName;
    public String offerpageproductname;
    pageObjectManager pageObjectManager;
    // setups setups1;
    setups setups;

    LandingPage LandingPageLandingPage;
    public LandingPageStepDefination(setups setups) {

        this.setups = setups;
    }

    @Given("user in greencart landing page")
    public void user_in_greencart_landing_page() {

         
    }

    @When("user search with shortname {string} and extrach actual name of product")
    public void user_search_with_shortname_and_extrach_actual_name_of_product(String Shrotname)
            throws InterruptedException {

        LandingPage LandingPage = setups.pageObjectManager.getMeLandingPage();
        LandingPage.searchItem(Shrotname);

         
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        setups.landingproductName = LandingPage.getProductName().split("-")[0].trim();
        System.out.println(landingproductName);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.